# What are the differences between the different input methods?

Tags: ibus, input-method

I am currently using iBus as input method (I am learning Japanese and Korean) which is default in Ubuntu but I don't like it very much (not sure why though).

I know there are other IMs like SCIM or uim but I couldn't find any comparisons.

I read that SCIM was replaced by iBus because it was buggy and didn't have support for gtk3 so I probably won't use this one but **what are differences between various IMs and why is iBus preferred**?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty new to using IME for Japanese myself. Like you, I've been studying Japanese but have little experience with IME's yet (except on Windo$e hehe). But I found this link to be a good starting point for some research into the matter. I haven't had much luck finding a straight up comparison myself, yet but I'll check back here and let you know if I find one ^~^ Here's a few links I *have* found, with some useful info:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JapaneseInput
- http://kmandla.wordpress.com/2008/02/19/unraveling-scim-and-uim/
- http://blogs.gnome.org/happyaron/2011/01/15/linux-input-method-brief-summary/

And finally when all else fails I check Wikipedia. It seems to help (a little xD):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_input_methods_for_UNIX_platforms
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uim

The following link isn't for Ubuntu specifically but it does explain a lot about IME's on Linux =):

- http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=18883

P.S. Oh and this is another alternative (it's called Mozc) =) It's based on Google Japanese IME. I'm not sure if it supports Korean but I know Google at least has a Korean IME so it might? I hope so! =)

- http://code.google.com/p/mozc/

I know this isn't exactly what you (and I) are looking for but I hope it helps! Ganbatte! ^~^

Comment: The blog from “happyaron” was worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

My experience will answer your question partially. I could get my wishes only working with SCIM, even though it’s largely unmaintained. iBus couldn’t do it. I need IME for Chinese:

- Wubi86 input (structure-based character input)
- smart pinyin input (sound-based character input)
- number-pinyin-to-accent-pinyin (letter-based letter input: I write `pin1yin1` and I get `pīnyīn`)
- switch between those via hotkey (iBus can’t do this; I use <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd>)
- don’t screw my dead keys (e.g. my Xserver is configured to do give me `ü` and `é` typing <kbd>¨</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> and <kbd>´</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> respectively – some input methods mess with this)